# infinite scroll clears existing data before adding new data unto page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project which contains infinite scrolling. When users scroll to the bottom of the page it loads up older posts by first clearing up what existed on the page except for it.

### Controller

```
app.controller('feedsctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.page=0;
    $scope.loadmore = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost/app/news.php?page='+$scope.page).success(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var i = data.length;
            $scope.posts = data;
            $scope.posts.push(data);
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            //console.log($scope.page);
            $scope.page +=1;
        });
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="feedsctrl" class="list card" ng-repeat="item in posts track by $index">
{{item.fullname}}<br>
{{item.username}}
</div>
```

Comment: You assign a value to $scope.posts, and then immediately push the same data to it. I'm not sure what the intended behaviour is there, but those two statements contradict one another.

Comment: Remove  `$scope.posts = data;`  and log `$scope.posts`   after `scroll.infiniteScrollComplete` and tell what are you getting ?

Comment: @ajeetlakhani, i've done that but now nothing shows at the view. read the comments below the answer and get updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.page=0;
  $scope.loadmore = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/app/news.php?page='+$scope.page).success(function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      $scope.posts.push(data[i]);
      }
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      //console.log($scope.page);
      $scope.page +=1;
    });
  };
}])
```

You are assigning data into $scope.posts before pushing it .You shouldn't be

Thanks

Comment: i tried it and nothing show at the view, even though the console returns variables from the server. i'm updating the question with the html part

Comment: can you show me your object structure , you are getting from php ?

Comment: [{"fullname":"max max","username":"max"},{"fullname":"linda linda","username":"userlinda"},{"fullname":"cal karl","username":"karl"}]

Comment: if you are getting response from php as an array .. you should use my updated answer (y)